# Installer with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

How can I do something like in this image?
[image]

Comment: sorry.. what? I don't understand your "question"....

Comment: sorry, i have created a installer with visual studio 2010 but personalize this with radio button fuction?

Answer (score 1):

In an MSI radio button controls are used inside a radio button group. Each radio button uses a value (for example **Button1Value** field in Properties pane). The value of the selected radio button is stored in the radio button group property (**ButtonProperty** field).

During install, you can use the radio button group property to determine what radio button was selected. For example, in your screen-shot **ButtonProperty** field is set to BUTTON3. So BUTTON3 property is set to "1" for the first radio button or to "2" for the second one.

If you need more information about this, give us more details about what you need to do based on the selected radio button.

Answer (score 0):

In your setup project in Visual Studio, open the `User Interface Editor`, right-click `Start` and select `Add Dialog`. In the dialog that appears, you can select `Radio buttons  (2 buttons)`

Comment: yes man but the radio button dos not personalize http://i51.tinypic.com/b4i3kp.png